# In Swift if I make something with 'let' than I can't change property but why keyPath is different?

Tags: swift

```
class Person{
    var name: String
    init(_ name: String){
        self.name = name
    }
}

struct Stuff{
    var name: String
    var owner: Person1
}

let jenna = Person("jenna")

var mac = Stuff(name: "Macbook pro", owner: jenna)

let ownerKeyPath = \Stuff.owner.name

mac[keyPath: ownerKeyPath] = "jerry"
```

I made jenna with 'let' keyword but if I use keyPath than I could change jenna's property.
How does it works?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Person is a reference type (a class). For a reference type, `let` just means that the reference itself cannot change, so `jenna` cannot be made to point to another object. But you can change any `var` properties within it (such as `name`. KeyPaths aren't related here. The same is true of regular property access:

```
mac.owner.name = "jerry"
```

If you want Person to behave like a value, so that its properties cannot change when it is marked with `let` (but can when it is marked with `var`), then it needs to be a struct, not a class. Then it will behave like Stuff.

Answer (score 1):

KeyPaths are irrelevant.

You made `Person.name` variable. As such, `mac.owner.name = "jerry"` works fine.

But it won't if you change `name` to `let`. That will make `ownerKeyPath` a `KeyPath`, not the `ReferenceWritableKeyPath` subclass of `KeyPath` that it is in your code. As with `let` constants, you can't set values using the `KeyPath` class.